# pytz Not Updating Hours on Timezone Change

Tags: python

For whatever reason, pytz doesn't seem to be changing the hour of the datetime object.

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

eastern = timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.now()).hour
central = timezone('US/central').localize(datetime.now()).hour

assert eastern != central # AssertionError
```

What do I need to do to fix this? I want to convert datetime.now() to a different datetime.

Comment: It's not a timezone "change" in your example because datetime.now() doesn't start with a timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that behavior is because datetime.now() returns a naive time. It doesn't add/subtract any time from it, because it doesn't have a way to know how much to add/subtract. To get the current datetime in a different timezone using pytz, just pass the timezone object to `datetime.now()`:

```
In [32]: eastern = datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern')).hour                                                                               

In [33]: central = datetime.now(timezone('US/Central')).hour                                                                               

In [34]: eastern                                                                                                                           
Out[34]: 18

In [35]: central                                                                                                                           
Out[35]: 17

In [36]: assert central != eastern                                                                                                         

In [37]:
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow... what a mess. "because it doesn't have a way to know how much to add/subtract" I actually think it does... try `timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.now()).strftime('%H')`. I'm really unimpressed with datetime handling in Python.

Comment: @fny you are calling `.strftime()` on an object you have already localized. `timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.now())` is essentially just assigning a timezone to a datetime object that doesn't have one.

Comment: Then why doesn't `timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.now()).hour` give the proper hour but the `strftime` version does?